# Root html (/index.html) can't be fetched. Returns 404

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http-status-code-404

**The dir structure is-**

```
MyApplication (Project Dir)

-static
   --inside static, I got different dirs containing images, css, htmls, etc
-some other dirs
-app.yaml
-index.py
-index.html
```

**The content of app.yaml is-**

```
application: MyApplicationID
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /favicon.ico
  static_files: static/images/favicon.ico
  upload: static/images/favicon.ico
  mime_type: image/x-icon

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: static/robots.txt
  upload: static/robots.txt

- url: /static
  static_dir: static  
  secure: optional

- url: /projects
  static_dir: projects  
  secure: optional

- url: /about
  static_dir: about  
  secure: optional

- url: /
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html

- url: /.*
  script: index.py
  secure: optional
```

Everything works fine except that if anything on the html pages are redirecting to "index.html" gets me a page not found (**"GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 404 -**) error. I tried follwing this - https://gist.github.com/873098 but still no luck. I tried other suggestions on other threads but still no luck. If I remove **- url: /** still no luck. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other person is right, you don't have an entry for the **url** `index.html`, like

```
- url: /index.html
  static_files: index.html
  upload: index.html
```

Edit 2: Just to be clear, no matter what is on the `static_files` line, this will still result in a URL of `http://mysite.com/index.html` even if the `static_files` line includes a subdirectory.

Comment: Didn't work and I don't want to have a dir like http://myURL.com/some_dir/index.html

Comment: You're misunderstanding! The directory on your computer has __nothing to do__ with the directory used to retrieve it. It's what's on the ` - url: ` line that sets that.

Comment: Just to let you know, the dir is not necessary. You just have to handle it from the script.  application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                                       [
                                         ('/', MainPage),
                                         ('/index.html', MainPage)
                                       ], debug=True)

Answer (score 1):

Requests for "/index.html" will be handled by index.py, given the contents of your app.yaml. Presumably you don't have a handler for "/index.html" in that file.

If you want index.html served for requests for "/index.html", add a mapping to app.yaml that matches the URL (or, just redirect to "/" instead of "/index.html" elsewhere in the site, which is less ugly)

Comment: I do.  def render(self,template_file,template_value):
        path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),template_file)
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_value))

Comment: def get(self):
         self.render('index.html', {})